# Disabling all buttons until an IBAction completed

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have four buttons on a single view. Each button has a different IBaction. Once one is pressed I would like to lock out all buttons from being pressed again until the action is completed. I have tried to give each one a property in the .h and then under each IBAction in the .m, I have set each of the four buttons like this `btnHelp.enabled =NO;`,`.`, etc and then at the end before the final } I have reenabled them all. This hasn't worked. I am a new to objective-C and xcode and greatly appreciate any help.

This is IOS. The .h code is :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnHelp;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSpin;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnScore;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnBet;

- (IBAction)slotHelp:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)slotSpin:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)slotBet:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)slotScore:(id)sender;
```

The .m is :

@synthesize btnHelp, btnScore, btnSpin, btnBet;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    btnHelp.enabled = NO;
    btnBet.enabled = NO;
    btnScore.enabled = NO;
    btnSpin.enabled = NO;

// do some introductory setup and give some spoken instructions
// Load plist data into array, etc
// Then reenable buttons

    btnHelp.enabled=YES;
    btnBet.enabled=YES;
    btnScore.enabled=YES;
    btnSpin.enabled=YES;
}

-(IBAction)slotHelp {

// Disable buttons while we complete action

        btnHelp.enabled = NO;
        btnBet.enabled = NO;
        btnScore.enabled = NO;
        btnSpin.enabled = NO;

// stuff to do

// Reenable buttons after action event completed

        btnHelp.enabled=YES;
        btnBet.enabled=YES;
        btnScore.enabled=YES;
        btnSpin.enabled=YES;
    }
```

There are three other action events for the other three buttons.

What I was trying to do is prevent accidental button presses during and action execution. I was hoping to have no chance of simultaneous button presses by accident. I am trying to make an app for use by physically challenged individuals who may accidentally press more than one button. I hope this helps explain a bit of why I want to block multiple presses even the same button.

Thanks for your interest and help.

Comment: iOS or OSX? Post the relevant code and explain the problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the most simple solution you may add a bool flag variable to your view class and add a check in you IBaction methods. Something like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    lock = true;
    // do some introductory setup and give some spoken instructions
    // Load plist data into array, etc
    // Then reenable buttons
    lock = false;
}

-(IBAction)slotHelp {
   if(!lock) {
      lock = true;
      //do what you need
      lock = false;
}
```

and do the same check for all the other IBActions

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Although this appears to be a very elegantly simple solution it seems after I added this code and as the speech from an action is speaking it is still possible to start other button press actions or even multiple actions. I guess the problem is halting all other IBActions until the speech is completed.

Comment: I implemented your code but added to the conditional `if`. `if (!lock && self.synthesizer.speaking == NO) { other code }` and this seems to work perfectly. Thanks so much for the simple solution.

Comment: By the way maybe if your introductory setup in each button action is rather small, it'll be executed fast so you can try to remove the lock variable from the code and leave just `if (self.synthesizer.speaking == NO) { other code }`

Comment: Yes you are correct. I didn't realize at first but what I really needed to do was check the speaking properties to make sure they had completed before allowing additional actions. Thanks for opening my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

As alternative way, you can globally block-unblock events with methods posted below, instead of blocking each button separately:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

and

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

But be careful. Wrong strategy of using of these methods can block your application.

Comment: Thank you for replying so promptly. As I mentioned in my comment below, I may need to incorporate a timer since each action has speech with it and I am trying to prevent overlap of actions either accidental or on purpose. I would like each action to complete before starting another action. Thanks for your patience and knowledge.